# Having trouble with std::string::compare() return values in c++

Tags: c++, string, compare

Relatively new to c++.

Having trouble understanding an issue I am having with the compare() function returning 1 instead of 0.

I have a program which reads a text file containing an arbitrary number of questions and answers for a quiz. It is formatted as such:

```
Q: How many days in a week?
A: seven
```

I have three files, main.cpp, Quiz.cpp, and Quiz.h:

main.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <fstream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <ctime>
#include <cstdlib>
#include "Quiz.h"

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char* argv[]){
    srand(unsigned(time(0)));

    vector<Quiz> quizVector;

    ifstream inputQuiz;

    inputQuiz.open(argv[1]);

    string q, a;
    int questionCount = 0;

    if(inputQuiz.is_open()){
        getline(inputQuiz, q);
        getline(inputQuiz, a);

        while(!inputQuiz.eof()){
            Quiz *instance = new Quiz(q, a);
            quizVector.push_back(*instance);

            questionCount++;

            getline(inputQuiz, q);
            getline(inputQuiz, a);
        }
    }
    random_shuffle(quizVector.begin(), quizVector.end());

    string userInput;

    for(int i = 0; i < questionCount; i++){
        cout << quizVector[i].getQuestion() << endl;
        cout << "A: ";
        getline(cin, userInput);
        
        if(quizVector[i].getAnswer().compare("A: " + userInput) == 0){
            cout << "Correct." << endl;
        }
        else{
            cout << "Incorrect." << endl;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Quiz.cpp:

```
#include <string>
#include "Quiz.h"

int Quiz::score = 0;

std::string Quiz::getQuestion(){
    return question;
}

std::string Quiz::getAnswer(){
    return answer;
}
```

Quiz.h:

```
#ifndef QUIZ_H
#define QUIZ_H

class Quiz{
    private:
        std::string question {""};
        std::string answer {""};
    public:
        Quiz() = default;
        Quiz(std::string q, std::string a) : question {q}, answer {a} {}
        std::string getQuestion();
        std::string getAnswer();
};

#endif
```

My problem lies within main.cpp:

```
for(int i = 0; i < questionCount; i++){
        cout << quizVector[i].getQuestion() << endl;
        cout << "A: ";
        getline(cin, userInput);

        if(quizVector[i].getAnswer().compare("A: " + userInput) == 0){
            cout << "Correct." << endl;
        }
        else{
            cout << "Incorrect." << endl;
        }
    }
```

When I input the correct answer corresponding to each question, compare() does not return 0, but consistently returns 1. There are no leading or trailing spaces at the start or ends of each line in the text file. Am I misunderstanding how getline() or compare() works? Is it something else? Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Why do you expect your answer to have `"A: "` at the front of it?

Comment: a progam to understand the value retuned from `compare` needs not be longer than 3-5 lines. You should create such a [mcve], if this toy program works as you expect then you know that `compare` isnt the problem, if not, you have a super nice example to post here.

Comment: @MarkRansom the answers in the file have `A: ` in front

Comment: You leak memory for no reason in `while` loop. Also take into account that `compare` is case-sensitive.

Answer (score 3):

I see a number of problems with this code:

- `std::random_shuffle()` is deprecated in C++14 and removed in C++17, use `std::shuffle()` instead.
- you are not validating that `argv` contains an input parameter before using it.
- Your use of `eof()` in the `while` loop is wrong.  For instance, if the last question/answer pair in the file is terminated by EOF instead of a line break, `getline()` will still return the question/answer to you, but it will also set the `eofbit` flag on the stream, which will cause `eof()` to return `true` and thus you will skip saving the last pair into the `vector`.  The stream is not technically in a failed state yet in this situation (see the diagram at https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/eof), so you shouldn't skip the last pair if it terminates with EOF rather than a line break.
- Your `while` loop is leaking memory.
- you don't need `questionCount` at all, use `quizVector.size()` instead. Or better, a [`range-for`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for) loop.
- you don't really need to use `compare()` at all, you can use `operator==` instead.  But, if you do use `compare()`, you should take into account that it is *case-sensitive* (as is `operator==`). You should also take advantage of the fact that `compare()` lets you specify an index to start comparing from, so you can ignore the `A:` prefix in the stored answer (alternatively, you could just strip off the `Q:` and `A:` prefixes when storing the question/answer in `Quiz`'s constructor).  Otherwise, you can use your compiler's `strcmpi()` function instead (if it offers one).

Try something more like this instead:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <fstream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <random>
#include <cctype>
#include "Quiz.h"

using namespace std;

string toLowercase(string s) {
    transform(s.begin(), s.end(), s.begin(), 
        [](unsigned char c){ return tolower(c); }
    );
    return s;
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]){

    if (argc < 2){
        cerr << "Please specify a file to open!" << endl;
        return 0;
    }

    ifstream inputQuiz(argv[1]);
    if (!inputQuiz.is_open()) {
        cerr << "Can't open the file!" << endl;
        return 0;
    }

    vector<Quiz> quizVector;
    string q, a, userInput;

    while (getline(inputQuiz, q) && getline(inputQuiz, a)) {
        quizVector.emplace_back(q, a);
    }

    random_device rd;
    mt19937 g(rd());
    shuffle(quizVector.begin(), quizVector.end(), g);

    for(auto &quiz : quizVector){
        cout << quiz.getQuestion() << endl;
        cout << "A: ";
        getline(cin, userInput);

        userInput = toLowercase(userInput);
        a = toLowercase(quiz.getAnswer());
        
        if (a == ("a: " + userInput)) {
        // or:
        // if (a.compare(2, string::npos, userInput) == 0) {
        // or, if you strip off "A:" beforehand:
        // if (a == userInput) {
            cout << "Correct." << endl;
        }
        else {
            cout << "Incorrect." << endl;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: @glwhitaker2 The issues I pointed out are already based on the original question as it was posted.  Do not modify a question in a way that will invalidate existing answers/comments. If you have *additional* information to add, you can certainly do that, but please append it to the existing content, do not replace the original content.